# Execute Mode ... C++ Code Blocks IDE Compiler Settings CLang for Linux

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, ide, codeblocks

Can someone share their compiler settings ..  CLANG...toolchain from CodeBlocks ?

Solution
**Edit in retrospect**
 ... Can I change the execute mode (chmod) on a particular hard drive partition?
Short term solution ... execute from the home directory

Since I only have comments below I am not sure I can mark an answer.
I will leave my misunderstanding below.

I am on Linux Mint

Partial Success .... Clang does appear to examine and compile code.

```
Cleaned "test200 - Debug"

-------------- Build: Debug in test200 (compiler: Clang Hand Labor)---------------

clang++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g     -c "/media/transcend/Seagate Replica/cpp2011/test200/test200/main.cpp" -o obj/Debug/main.o
clang++  -o bin/Debug/test200 obj/Debug/main.o    
Output size is 27.32 KB
Process terminated with status 0 (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 0 seconds)
```

Console Output  (typed by Hand .... I cannot copy from tiny console of CodeBlocks)
This is the !!!Error!! ... Just cout << "Hello"

```
elided
sh: 1: /path/st200 permission denied

returned 126
```

Compiler Settings in CodeBlocks IDE
C..clang
C++ clang++
Linker clang++
Linker for static ... ar
Resource Compiler ... nothing
make program ...........make

I used Software Manager of Linux for CodeBlocks IDE
There was no CLANG options present  ... this fact makes me think I have something old
I copied the GCC Settings and typed clang and clang++
Thanks

Build Log Elided

```
clang++ -Wall -fexceptions  -g  -I/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/include  elided -Wcast-qual    -c "/media/transcend2020/Seagate Replica/cpp2011/test200/test200/main.cpp" -o obj/Debug/main.o

clang++  -o bin/Debug/test200 obj/Debug/main.o   -lLLVMAsmParser elided  -L/usr/lib/llvm-3.2/lib  -lpthread -lffi -ldl -lm  
Output size is 51.20 KB
```

Comment: “clang” is not an acronym … hence it’s not written “CLANG”.

Comment: @K  !! Balshoi Cpaciba !!

Comment: Don't know anything about Code Blocks really but aren't you trying to compile the source file actually located on Windows ntfs partition? It looks like compiler doesn't have permission to read from that partition. Try to copy the source file to your home folder.

Comment: @Dmitry ...  I created new project to relocate project. This caused a normal include to fail...  Linux Mint is not on its own partition.  This is an option of Linux Mint.  It was installed within MS Windows. ....  ERROR    ...  /home/transcend2020/cpp2013/testinhome/main.cpp|1|fatal error: 'iostream' file not found|   Investigating

Comment: @Dmitry  The computer was originally Windows 7.  Now Dual Boot ... within the current partition.  I tried to change permissions from File Manager Properties ... Linux does not allow me  make some changes even though I click on interface  ... (I am not expert in this) ..Owner Access Read and Write ......Group Access None ...Other Access None ...Execute NOT checked ... and I cannot change it ... External Hard Drive

Comment: @Dmitry . Thanks.  Situation has temporarily be come SUCCESSFUL. This question is closed at this moment. ............. CodeBlocks Crashed.   Then I opened again. Deleted Compiler Settings that I created for [Clang]  ... Created New [Clang] Settings. Then at this moment I got results. Small Program was successful.  I have no logical explanation for what happened.  I did not audit myself.  Perhaps I should close this and find my new problems.

Comment: @Dmitry. Additional Tests Reveal. Home Directory has execute mode set.  External Hard Drive has execute mode .. NOT set.  I do not know how to change it. (Graphical File Manager and not chmod). I did not understand how earlier ... iostream not found.... copy and paste elided ...sh: 1: /media/transcend2020/Seagate Replica/path/second_test: Permission denied

Process returned 126 (0x7E)   execution time : 0.001 s
Press ENTER to continue.

Comment: differences in execute status ..........  anybody@linuxmint /media/elide/Seagate Replica/cpp2011/second_test_execute/second_test/bin/Debug $ ls -l
total 84
**-rw-------** 1 transcend2020 transcend2020 84283 Nov 24 22:59` second_test  ...........

anybody@linuxmint ~/cpp2013/test200/test204/test204/bin/Debug $ ls -l
total 84
**-rwxr-xr-x** 1 transcend2020 transcend2020 84186 Nov 24 22:41 test204 ...   There are articles at SO talking about mode differences on different partitions